# breaking up a long regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

Problem: I am using R and stringr and I have a very long regular expression using the "or" operator that I save to an object and use with stringr. How can I break it up into multiple lines in R so I do not have to keep scrolling to the right in my source editor? When I try commas, only the first line is recognized. Most answers to this question have been for other programming languages (i.e. not R).

```
regex_of_sites <- "side|southeast|north|computer|engineer|first|south|pharm|left|southwest|level|second|thirteenth"
```

Comment: So you should use the _ignore whitespace_ option and **[format](http://www.regexformat.com)** your code.after you make a full **[trie](http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg)** out of it `(?x)(?:computer|engineer|first|le(?:ft|vel)|north|pharm|s(?:econd|ide|outh(?:east|west)?)|thirteenth)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression is just a string. You can paste it together across multiple lines like any other string

```
regex_of_sites <- paste0("side|southeast|north|computer|engineer|",
     "first|south|pharm|left|southwest|",
     "level|second|thirteenth")
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using the pattern with stringr methods that use ICU regex flavor, you may use a `(?x)` free spacing (also called verbose, or ignore pattern whitespace) modifier where all unescaped whitespace is ignored when compiling the pattern, and there is a possibility to add comments after an unescaped `#` on each line (so, all literal `#` must be escaped).

Here is an example:

```
> library(stringr)
> regex_of_sites <- "(?x)side     # Term 0
+ |southeast                      # Term 1
+ |north                          # Term 1
+ |computer                       # Term 2
+ |engineer
+ |first
+ |south
+ |pharm
+ |left
+ |southwest
+ |level
+ |second
+ |thirteenth"
> str_extract_all("first level", regex_of_sites)
[[1]]
[1] "first" "level"
```

The same modifier is supported by the PCRE patterns used in base R regex functions with `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: What is the `+` in the middle of the regex for. Is it for string parsing ? It can't be for the regex.

Comment: @sln It is a copy paste from the R environment.